# How to avoid IE message "... allow this webpage to access the clipboard" programmatically?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, clipboard, paste

Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVfGY/3/). I'd like to catch the IE paste event, do s.th. with the data to be pasted and paste it then. This should also be possible to be done by clicking a button. Everything works so far except one really annoying thing...

When clicking on the button **first** the IE will ask you to allow access to the clipboard. But if you reload the page and first paste s.th. with the shortcut key CTRL + V, there will be no question and even if you now try to use the button, IE will not ask you anymore.

For me it looks like I'm using the same code in both cases. So is it maybe possible to do s.th so that IE will not bother the user even if he clicks the button first?

Here's an extract of my code:

```
$("div").bind("paste", function (e) { customPaste(); });

function customPaste() {
 if (event) event.returnValue = false;
 var data = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
 paste(data);
}
```

Comment: The docs are here, but I couldn't see a reference to the security prompt (so not very good documentation!): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms536436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx